# What does "Learning from the best" precisely mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “You sound like a complete cynic.”
>
> **Learning from the best** did that to a person. My dad’s pretty standoffish.

[source - One Week Girlfriend](http://khnovel.com/one-week-girlfriend/page-3-10042110.html)
I looked it up, and found out several songs.
Is it a commendatory term or a derogatory term here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the literal meaning is clear. It means you learned something by being with an expert.

> I played football in a club with Pele, so I learned from the best.

In this context, person A says that person B is "cynical"

Person B says that they learned to be cynical because their Dad is the best at being cynical: To paraphrase

> You are cynical
>
> I am cynical because my dad was the most cynical and emotionally distant person.